# Receiving Drag events on an NSWindow when the window contains a single WebView view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, webview, nswindow

I am new to objective-c and cocoa so please break things down for me.  I'm working on a project started by another developer and have only been working in objective-c for 3 days.

I have an NSWindow subclass that contains a WebView view.  The WebView content that is loaded is a Silverlight plugin.  I registered the NSWindow to receive Drag events.  The drag events are being generated but only when the drag occurs within the NSWindow Title Bar.  I register for the drag events in the load method.

AdminWindow.mm

```
#import "AdminWindow.h"
#import "NativeMessageReceiver.h"

extern AdminWindow* adminRiaWindow;

@implementation AdminWindow

@synthesize adminWebView;

BOOL isAdminContentLoaded;


-(void) load
{
    if (!isAdminContentLoaded)
    {
        NSLog(@"loading Admin window");

        NSString *curDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"file://%@/Contents/Resources/RIA/AdminContentMac.html",curDir];

        [[adminWebView mainFrame] loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]]];
        [adminWebView setDrawsBackground:NO];

        id win = [adminWebView windowScriptObject];
        NativeMessageReceiver* receiver = [NativeMessageReceiver getInstance];
        [win setValue:receiver forKey:@"NativeMessageReceiver"];   
        receiver.adminWebView = adminWebView;   

        isAdminContentLoaded = YES;
    }
}      

-(void) show
{
    [self load];        

    [self setIsVisible: YES];

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [self makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
    [self makeMainWindow];
    [self center];
}

-(void) hide
{
    [self setIsVisible: NO];
}

- ( BOOL ) windowShouldClose  : ( id ) sender
{
    [self setIsVisible: NO];

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeMainWindow
{
    return YES;
}

@end

extern "C" void ShowAdminWindow()
{
    NSLog(@"showing Admin window");
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
        [adminRiaWindow performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    else 
    {
        [adminRiaWindow show];
    }   
}

extern "C" void HideAdminWindow()
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [adminRiaWindow performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hide) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        [adminRiaWindow hide];
    }

}
```

CustomeWebView

```
@implementation SteamPunkWebView
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
        NSLog(@"In Custom View Init");
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to layer a transparent NSView over WebView and have the transparent view handle the drag events. Just have to figure out how to layer a NSView over the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only getting drag events in the title bar because you registered the *window* to receive the events, not the *web view*.

Try this instead:

```
    [self.adminWebView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
```

Comment: If I register the view as indicated above, I get no events at all.  I'm guessing I would then need subclass WebView and have it implement the appropriate drag event handlers instead of the Window?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct to me. Alternatively, you could ask the view to forward its drag events to the window. There's a recipe here for something similar: http://www.stone.com/The_Cocoa_Files/Ins_and_Outs_of_Drag_and_D.html

Answer (score 0):

`WebView`s are one of the most complex views in Cocoa and are a special case when it comes to dragging. Instead of implementing the standard `NSView` dragging behaviour, you need instead to set an object as the web view's `WebUIDelegate` and implement the following delegate method:

[`‑webView:dragDestinationActionMaskForDraggingInfo:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001915-CJBDFIDG)

You can then control how you want the web view to respond to the drag action. The `WebUIDelegate` protocol has several other methods to control dragging, so you should read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001915-CJBDFIDG) for more detail.

To actually receive the dragged objects and process them, you will need to subclass `WebView` and implement `‑draggingEnded:`.

You definitely do *not* need to add any dragging methods to the window itself.

Comment: The documentation seems to refer to the sending web view.  In my situation, I'm dragging an item from Finder or the Desktop over the WebView.  Is your answer still applicable?

Comment: Yes. This method works for all dragging operations, not just web view to web view drags. If you need to customise the dragging operations further, you can of course subclass the web view and override the various dragging methods that you've overridden in your `NSWindow` code.

Comment: I definitely need to process and forward the drag events so I subclassed WebView but I'm not seeing the initWithFrame method even being called.  Please see updated code above.  @noa

Comment: Can you give me some code example on how I use the WebUIDelegate with my subclassed WebView? @noa

Comment: If the WebView is instantiated in Interface Builder then `initWithCoder:` will be called instead of `initWithFrame:`. You don't need to call `registerForDraggedTypes`, you only need to implement the delegate method I mentioned and `draggingEnded:`. In the `WebUIDelegate` method, you should look at the types passed in to the pasteboard (accessed from the `draggingInfo` parameter) and then return either `WebDragDestinationActionNone` to reject the drag or `WebDragDestinationActionAny` to accept it. You then process the dropped items in `draggingEnded`.

Comment: I'm still not sure my custom view is being instantiated and I'm not using Interface Builder.  So, in my subclassed WebView, I implement `dragDestinationActionMaskForDraggingInfo`?  Reject or accept the drag and process dropped items in draggingEnded?  I'm also interested though in draggingEntered, draggingUpdated, and draggingExit.

Comment: @noa I solved my issue by adding a transparent nsview to my window's content view `[[self contentView] addSubview:dragView];`  The custom view is registered and handles drag events over the window.  Unfortunately, extending WebView and using the WebUIDelegate wasn't working for me.  If you have some more ideas or can offer up a detailed example that fits my situation, I would love to get it working using the WebUIDelegate as I feel using a transparent subview is kind of a jurry rigged approach.